# Coping properties file automatically with Gradle to the same directories after the build

Tags: java, gradle, automation

I am working on a Java project that contains many properties files and the structure looks like this:

```
src
   |
    -main
        |
         -java
             |
              -ui
                |
                 -many directories with property file in each directory.
```

I want to build fat jar using Gradle build that will contain those files in the same directories.

Something like:

```
build
   |
    -classes
        |
         -java
             |
              -main
                |
                 -ui.... and all the files like above.
```

How can I to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By convention gradle will package all the properties (and other resource) files placed under `src/main/resources` into the final jar artifact.

If you are sure that you still want to place your properties file under `src/main/java` then you can configure `resources` source sets location using the following snippet in your `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources { 
      srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
      include "**/*.properties"
    }
  }
}
```

The properties files will not end up in `build/classes` but will be part of you jar. You you want them to be `build/classes/java` as well (not recommended), then you need to configure the output dir for resources as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42553876/469414) answer.

Comment: Thanks. that helped for my case.

Comment: @user2370545 please accept the answer if it has answered your question :)